# ffmpeg live preview before saving video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I use [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) for Android and it works fine, but I have an issue with a live preview before saving the video. For example, I create video with some filters and want to show result fo user before saving it. I didn't find ffplay for android. Does somebody know if there is a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ffplay` is not available there is an alternative.

If Android supports SDL, and your `ffmpeg` has support for it, you can use the [SDL output device](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#sdl).

The SDL output device (and `ffplay`) requires `SDL.h` to be available during compilation. It will be automatically detected so no additional `./configure` options are needed. (However, if `SDL.h` is available there are few reasons for `ffplay` not to be available.)

You can check to see if it is available with:

```
$ ffmpeg -devices
  […]
  E sdl,sdl2        SDL2 output device
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "realtime,scale=iw/2:-1,negate,format=yuv420p" -f sdl -
```

- The [realtime](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#realtime_002c-arealtime) filter is required or it will try to process the filters as fast as possible resulting in fast play.
- The [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter is required to output a pixel format that is compatible with the SDL output device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. After executing your command I see `E/mobile-ffmpeg: [sdl,sdl2 @ 0xdcd7d600] Unable to initialize SDL: Application didn't initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?` error. Could you please give me the correct direction for solving this issue?

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko Sorry, but I don't have any Android experience.